# Scraping multiple pages into list with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I wrote out a scraper program using beautifulsoup4 in Python that iterates through multiple pages of cryptocurrency values and returns the the opening, highest, and closing values. The scraping part of the issue works fine but  can't get it to save all of the currencies into my lists, only the last one gets added to the list.

Can anyone help me out on how to save all of them? I've done hours of searching and can't seem to find a relevant answer. The code is as follows:

```
no_space = name_15.str.replace('\s+', '-')

#lists out the pages to scrape 
for n in no_space:
    page = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/' + n + '/historical-data/'
    http = lib.PoolManager()
    response = http.request('GET', page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.data, "lxml")

    main_table = soup.find('tbody')

    date=[]
    open_p=[]
    high_p=[]
    low_p=[]
    close_p=[]

    table = []

    for row in main_table.find_all('td'):
        table_pull = row.find_all_previous('td') #other find methods aren't returning what I need, but this works just fine

    table = [p.text.strip() for p in table_pull]

    date = table[208:1:-7]
    open_p = table[207:1:-7]
    high_p = table[206:1:-7]
    low_p = table[205:1:-7] 
    close_p = table[204:0:-7]

    df=pd.DataFrame(date,columns=['Date'])
    df['Open']=list(map(float,open_p))
    df['High']=list(map(float,high_p))
    df['Low']=list(map(float,low_p))
    df['Close']=list(map(float,close_p))
    print(df)
```

Comment: In you for loop, you are overwriting your `table_pull` variable so only the last row is being processed. You have to indent the code after the loop so it is executed inside the loop, also making sure you append to dataframe instead of assigning (`df[...] = list(...` lines).

Comment: Thanks @hoefling and @rahlf23! It's gonna take me a bit more work to rewrite those aspects of it but now that I know where I went wrong it should be considerably easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put, it looks like you are accessing all 'td' elements and then attempting to access the previous elements of that list, which is unnecessary. Also, as @hoefling pointed out, you are continuously overwriting your variable inside of your loop, which is the reasoning for why you are only returning the last element in the list (in other words, only the last iteration of your loop sets the value of that variable, all previous ones are overwritten). Apologies, I cannot test this out currently due to firewalls on my machine. Try the following:

```
no_space = name_15.str.replace('\s+', '-')

#lists out the pages to scrape 
for n in no_space:
    page = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/' + n + '/historical-data/'
    http = lib.PoolManager()
    response = http.request('GET', page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.data, "lxml")

    main_table = soup.find('tbody')

    table = [p.text.strip() for p in main_table.find_all('td')]

    #You will need to re-think these indices here to get the info you want
    date = table[208:1:-7]
    open_p = table[207:1:-7]
    high_p = table[206:1:-7]
    low_p = table[205:1:-7] 
    close_p = table[204:0:-7]

    df=pd.DataFrame(date,columns=['Date'])
    df['Open']=list(map(float,open_p))
    df['High']=list(map(float,high_p))
    df['Low']=list(map(float,low_p))
    df['Close']=list(map(float,close_p))
    print(df)
```